# jQuery Datepicker range highlight on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to highlight the range between the 2 dates on hover. I managed to make it work but only on select.

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#startdate").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#enddate").val());
    return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcL9toag/)

To see what I want ... Please select from Start a date and then from End a date and then click again on End and you will see the range highlighted with orange. How can I make that highlight on hover while the End datepicker is still open?

Comment: Did you managed to get this to work?